# Python + JIRA API: Add users to group by email addresses

Tags: python, rest, api, jira

I'm struggling with my thoughts. Since I'm a newbie right now I need your help. I've created a .csv file with some email addresses. This addresses are active users in our Jira - and I want them in one specific group. And I really don't know how to do it in Python yet.

I'm connected via API and able to get user info etc. But I want to get them into this one specific group.

Do you know a way of solution? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-group-user-post

This is the add user to group api. You could simply create a function that has accountId as its parameter. Then you can just iterate through the users you have and call that function with their accountId.